# Why is that $\int_{-L}^{L} \cos{\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}dx=\delta_{mn}L$ does not work for $m=0$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-series, orthogonality

I have this expression $$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos{\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}dx$$ my book says that this is equal to $$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos{\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}dx=\delta_{mn}L$$ except when  $m=0$. In this case, it says, we have $$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}dx=2L\delta_{0n}$$

> Why is that?

If I put $m=0$ I will have $$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}dx=\left[\frac{L\sin{(\frac{n\pi x}{L})}}{n\pi}\right]_{-L}^L=\frac{L}{n\pi}[\sin{(n\pi)}-\sin{(-n\pi)}]=\frac{2L(-1)^n}{n\pi}$$ how do they obtain that?

Comment: Note that you have to handle the case $n=0$ separately, since the first equality doesn't hold then (because you would be dividing by zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=0$ we have

$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(n\pi x/L)\,dx=\int_{-L}^L (1)\,dx=2L \tag 1$$

And for $n\ne 0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-L}^L \cos(n\pi x/L)\,dx&=\left.\left(\frac{\sin(n\pi x/L)}{n\pi /L}\right)\right|_{-L}^L \\\\
&=\frac{\sin(n\pi )-\sin(-n\pi)}{n\pi/L}\\\\
&=0\tag 2
\end{align}$$

since $\sin(n\pi )=0\ne (-1)^n$ for all integer $n$.

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we find that

$$\int_{-L}^L \cos(n\pi x/L)\,dx=2L\delta_{n,0}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: oh right. Then it should always be zero, and not $2L\delta_{0n}$ right?

Comment: No, when $n=0$ the argument doesn't work. @Euler_Salter

Comment: @Euler_Salter : See my comment on the original question above

Comment: @MPW right! I need to divide into two cases again, it makes sense!